# How is the convolution of images properly defined?

Tags: convolution, image-processing

In [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Details), the convolution is defined as $$(g*f)(x,y):=\sum_{dx=-a}^a\sum_{dy=-b}^b\omega(dx,dy)f(x-dx,y-dy).\tag1$$ The image $f$ is obviously understood as a function on $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$. Now, regardless of what we insert for $x$ and $y$ in $(1)$, the sum in $(1)$ will always contain terms where $f$ is evaluated outside $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$.

So, my question is: How can this be fixed? How is $g\ast f$ defined in practice?

There is an [edge handling section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Edge_handling), but what I don't get is that the problem I've described above does not only occur at the edges. It occurs regardless of what we insert for $x$ and $y$. Maybe (please let me know if I'm right) this is because one usually assumes that the support of $\omega$ is very small ... Because otherwise, something like "wrapping around" the values of $f$ should yield very weird results.

Comment: Use zero-padding. Take a look at MATLAB's [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)

Comment: If an index falls outside the image, then we have to do a choice on how to "pad" the image. Commonly we just fill with zeros if needed, but there are other choices (mirroring, etc) because it produces artifacts. Sometimes the resulting image is smaller (ie we cut ou the pixels where the convolution window falls outside the image). It's a matter of choice.

Answer (score 1):

That equation doesn't describe the convolution of two images ($f * g$), but the convolution of a kernel with an image yielding a different image ($ g = \omega * f$) - notice that you miscopied it a bit.

And yes, kernels typically have small support, often having only a 3*3 non-zero block, and rarely larger than 5*5.

You can convolve two images, using periodicity or zero-padding like you say, but the result gets rather "information theoretical", and doesn't look anything like either of the original images, at least to the average human eye.